# Renaming files at command line to a different length filename

Tags: command-line, rename, file-rename

I need to rename multiple files in a directory. They can be copied to another directory if necessary.

The filenames will be in the format `57.jpg, 57-1.jpg, 57-2.jpg` etc. The suffix may be double digits.

I can't figure out how you would rename them if the destination is a different length.

So `ren 57*.jpg 1234*.jpg or ren 57*.jpg 3*.jpg` will alter the characters that I need intact (the -1, -2 etc).

I have a list of the start of the files and what they need to change to (eg: `57` becomes `1234`, `59` becomes `3214`, `598` becomes `3215` and so on).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which shell do you use? You should specify it on a tag to attract the right answers.

Comment: @Dave -- what shell are you using? I am pretty sure you will need some sort of loop here. I can help with a rename loop foreach file in your directory

Comment: I attempted `rename file-2020-20-*.pdf file-2020-*.pdf` where after the -, files can have different dates.  My attempt was a consistent pattern in terms of length just the rename to length was different than rename from length.  This is failing for me too.  I made my attempt in Windows command line (cmd) in Windows 10.  The reason for above was an earlier pattern rename failed and produced results like that latest attempt.  another example of the failure would be:  `rename myFile-2020-*.pdf mine2020-*.pdf` producing end-refesults like this - `minele-2020-01-09.pdf`.  Thoughts anyone?